# MySQL: Query with ORDER BY clause returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my *MySQL* database, I have a table called `pages` and it contains several columns, two of which are `order (int)`, `tab (int)`, and `name (text)`.  When I call a query as such

```
"SELECT * FROM pages WHERE tab = '$tid'"
```

it executes with no problem, returning all rows with the correct tab label. The problem I am having is when I execute with an `ORDER BY` :

```
"SELECT * FROM pages WHERE tab = '$tid' ORDER BY order ASC"
```

I get a return of false from the query.  No errors either.
When I put the column `order` in single quotes `'`, the query works like it did before, but applies no order.

Why am I getting no return regardless of which column I try to sort by?  How do I make my query sort to a column correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved word in MySQL, so you should escape it with backticks `` ` `` if you want to use it as an identifier :

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE tab = '$tid' ORDER BY `order`
```

Comment: Yup! ORDER is a reserved word and needs to be escaped when used as column name.

Comment: @Bit Fracture : Here is a [list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) of all reserved words

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error is not coming out. Try the following:

```
select * from pages order by `order`;
```

`ORDER` is a reserved word. If you not quote it properly the query will not run.